# add an invisible paragraph in a word document using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a word document (.docx) that contains some information, I want to edit this document and add to it some text , I want that the text still invisible when I open the document but I want also to access to it easily from my code.
 Do you have please any idea how can I proceed ?

Comment: Is make the text white out of the question?

Comment: my problem is where to put that text , for example if I use a paragraph, how can I read it after a while and recognize it knowing that the document contains many paragraphs

Comment: There are several ways you can create text that doesn't appear in the document. You could make the text white, but it would still take up space in the document. You could add it to the Quick Parts, or you could add it as a document property. These things are still visible to the user, but not as part of the document. I am sure there are others. I am going to VTC as this is far to general, and a complete answer could fill a short book. Consider editing your question to be more specific. [ask] may help

Answer (score 1):

I was in fact looking for a solution with ApachePOI to make my text invisible in the generated word document.After some researches, I found this solution:

```
for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : doc.getParagraphs()){
for(XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()){
CTOnOff onoffnull = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance();
run.getCTR().getRPr().setVanish(onoffnull);
}
}
```

this code make all paragraphs of a word document invisible by the user.

Comment: in case getRPr() returns null you can do  `run.getCTR().addNewRPr().setVanish(onoffnull);`